# any chance of having java plugin in firefox 53+?

Tags: firefox, java

On Firefox 52 we could still enable java with `about:config`'s `plugin.load_flash_only`=false.

That does not work on 53+. But since the NAPI interface still exists for flash (why!?) is there any way to force Firefox 53+ to load the java plugin that is already available to it and it stubbornly refuses to load?

Comment: Java in browsers is dead. If you still need it, consider using an ESR release of Firefox.

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/npapi-plugins java support, along with other plugins, was explicitly blocked. Flash was given a temporary reprieve due to it being very prevalent, but it too should be considered harmful.

Comment: I get that this is the official mozilla/google message. But its kinda silly to use a browser without the latest security updates to access online banking. Specially because the latest browsers still support the plugin api for flash of all things. If they had disabled the insecure API entirely, i'd buy that without looking for a patch, but since the api is there, there must be a way.

Comment: You could learn how to code and find out how they are blacklisting the plugins and then compile your own version of the browser with support re-enabled... It depends on how exactly they removed support. Might be that other forks of Firefox works with java. Waterfox looks like it might but there are no current "mainstream" browsers that support it, it is just too dangerous.

Comment: Just out of curisity: What online banking still requires a Java plugin? The plugin has been deprecated for at least three years.

Comment: “But its kinda silly to use a browser without the latest security updates to access online banking.” No, it’s actually the other way around. Depending on Java Applets in 2018(!) is what’s silly. You should seriously consider switching to a different bank.

Comment: I am considering switching banks. But remember: any hack on my account via their systems is their financial responsibility. They are not securing their money, not mine. And firefox is deciding what is prevalent from their point of view. I use this bank that requires java. I have never visited a site that required flash since 2001 or 2!

Answer (score 2):

> But since the NAPI interface still exists for flash (why!?) is there
>   any way to force Firefox 53+ to load the java plugin that is already
>   available to it and it stubbornly refuses to load?

**tl;dr: No, there is not . Use an ESR release (as of 2018) if you need Java.**

No, there is not, at least not if you use an official binary provided by the Mozilla foundation. [Firefox as provided by Mozilla no longer supports NPAPI plugins, except for Flash](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/npapi-plugin), and there is no way to re-enable them.

It is probably true that the "NAPI interface still exists for Flash", but to use it to load the Java plugin, you would have to create your own modified build of Firefox. I don't know how difficult this would be (maybe some parts of NPAPI were already removed because Flash does not need them), but unless you have experience in software development and specifically in C++, it will be *a lot* of work (as in weeks or even months).

Specifically for people like you who still need features from older versions of Firefox, there is the ESR (Extended-support release) version of Firefox. From the page linked above:

> In case you’re not yet ready for this transition to happen, the ESR
>   (Extended Support Release) of Firefox 52 will continue to support
>   these plugins until early 2018. Click [here](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/organizations/all/) to download Firefox ESR.

So realistically, if you need Java in Firefox, your only option is Firefox ESR. At least for now - the ESR version 52.x [will be supported at least until August 2018](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/). The next ESR release will be based on Firefox Quantum and will probably not support Java. *Thanks to  Daniel B for pointing this out*.

Comment: It’s not just “not forever”. It’s [well-documented](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/) that support for the 52.x ESR line is planned to last until August 28, 2018. The next ESR release will be based on Firefox Quantum and will probably not support Java.

Comment: @DanielB:Thanks for the hint. I took the liberty of adding it to my answer.

Comment: you ignored my main point, and contradicted yourself. NPAPI is available, only to flash. My point is, if they choose to make me vulnerable via flash, why can't I choose to make me vulnerable via java too?

Comment: @gcb: Sorry, I don't understand. How do I contradict myself?

Comment: As to "if they choose to make me vulnerable via flash, why can't I choose to make me vulnerable via java too?": As I wrote, you _can_ in fact do that, however only by modifying the Firefox source code. Now why Mozilla _decided_ to do this is a different question (which you are free to ask separately). The short answer is that they wanted to dump NPAPI completely but made an exception for Flash due to its popularity.

Comment: @sleske You say the api is not available anymore. But then say it is there, but just for flash. So the API is available.

Comment: @gcb: The API is available for the Flash plugin, but (deliberately) not for any other plugin - no contradiction there. That's what I wrote.